# Finch Robot (Java) - Should Light Up and Say the Colour When It Is Tapped

Tags: java, if-statement

I wrote a code for the finch robot in Java that should light up and say the name of the colour when it is tapped but at the moment when I tap nothing happens. 
It works without the if statement but when I add it nothing happens. 
Does anyone know why? 
Thank you

```
import edu.cmu.ri.createlab.terk.robot.finch.Finch;

import java.awt.Color;

public class FinchUserInteraction {

    // create finch object
    static Finch myFinch = new Finch(); 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //'BlueFinch' is the name of the blue Finch object 
        myFinch = new Finch();


        if (myFinch.isTapped() == true) {
            myFinch.setLED(Color.blue, 500);
            myFinch.saySomething("Blue");
        } else {
            myFinch.setLED(Color.orange);
        }

        myFinch.quit(); 
        System.exit(0); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if is about the if statement. It looks fine, you could do simply `if(myFinch.isTapped())` instead though. You could put a breakpoint and debug to see step by step. And what do you mean by nothing happens? What happens when it works?(Without if statement?)

Comment: maybe try with while loop.

Comment: Could you post the rest of your code? The Finch class

Comment: Note that you are assigning twice a new Finch instance to `myFinch`.

Comment: Depends on how the robot works. It's possible that what you wrote only runs once - that is, you start the robot, it checks if it's tapped (it's not yet), so it sets led to orange and exits. If you want it to light blue whenever you tap it, you will need to write your code a different way.

Comment: without the if statement it lights up and says "Blue". But I want it to light up only if it is tapped.

Comment: `It works without the if statement but when I add it nothing happens.` -> Because isTapped() is returning `false` apparently. Are you tapping the robot?

Comment: I figured out that myFinch.isTapped() is not very accurate.

Comment: if anyone else tries to do something similar use myFinch.isObstacle() == true and a while loop instead of a if loop for it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that myFinch.isTapped() is not very accurate. 
If anyone else tries to do something similar use myFinch.isObstacle() == true and a while loop instead of a if statement for it to work

Answer (score 0):

Your if-statement only checks the value of `myFinch.isTapped()` once, and immediately closes afterward. Problem: `myFinch.isTapped()` may only work on one frame and immediately stop afterward.